# How to open Url in Webview when it is come from another activity and inside the String

Tags: android, webview

i am making a app where i make on service call and after success of that call i got one `URL` after this i send that url through the intent to the my `webview` activity.

following is the code

```
 if (response.code() == 200) {

                String xyz = response.body();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CCAWebViewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("key",xyz);
                startActivity(intent);
```

here in to the call i got one url which i store in `xyz` and i pass this `xyz` to the next activity .

CCAWebViewActivity.class code

```
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String web = bundle.getString("key");

webView.loadUrl(web);
setContentView(webView);
```

i got that url here through intent so my question is how i open that url which is in side the string in webview when i run this code i got follwoing error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2335)
```

so please tell me anyone how to open url in webview when it is inside a 
String.

Comment: can you share your code seems like you're adding two views

Comment: Commenting out / Deleting `setContentView(webView);` might solve your issue.

Comment: @EndreBörcsök thanks it done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not passing the URL as a String, your problem is the call after that line:

```
setContentView(webView);
```

It seems that webView is already added into the Activity... So just change the URL and remove this call.

Comment: my url is dynamic  every time

Comment: On each change of the url, you will have to call webView.loadUrl(web);